# Exception handling with Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMq

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a problem finding any information about exception handling in Spring Cloud Stream. I know that there is the `errorChannel` which is suppose to handle exceptions but I have no idea how to use it. Could anyone give me any samples? Currently, when I send an event to my sink (`@StreamListener(target = Sink.SAMPLE)`) and  during processing `MessageHandlingException` will occur, I only get the log and there is no mechanism to notify my source. I tried using `@ControllerAdvice in my sink application` and catch exception in classic Spring MVC style, but I don't think it's how it supposed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binder currently does not publish to the error channel; we are reworking that for the next release so you will be able to consume exceptions in the app.

Currently, you can use the `autoBindDlq` and `republishToDlq` properties to send the exceptions (with error information in the headers) to a dead letter queue; you can then consume from that queue.

Comment: This is a very old question/answer; yes; the framework now supports error channels; you should refer to the current documentation and ask a new question if something is not clear.